# Auto-growing margins when screen width get stretched

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin, grid-layout

I have a list (`<ul />`) that I try to display as a grid. The *cells* have a fixed width (let's say 100px): the number of cols and rows depends then on the screen resolution.

When the screen has a large width, there are many columns but few lines:

```
   ______________________________________________________________
  |   ___________    ___________    ___________    ___________   |
  |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
  |  |    #1     |  |    #2     |  |    #3     |  |    #4     |  |
  |  |<- 100px ->|  |<- 100px ->|  |<- 100px ->|  |<- 100px ->|  |
  |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
  |  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |
  |   ___________                                                |
  |  |           |                                               |
  |  |    #5     |                                               |
  |  |<- 100px ->|                                               |
  |  |           |                                               |
  |  |___________|                                               |
  |______________________________________________________________|
```

When the screen has a small width, there are few columns but many lines:

```
               ________________________________
              |   ___________    ___________   |
              |  |           |  |           |  |
              |  |    #1     |  |    #2     |  |
              |  |<- 100px ->|  |<- 100px ->|  |
              |  |           |  |           |  |
              |  |___________|  |___________|  |
              |   ___________    ___________   |
              |  |           |  |           |  |
              |  |    #3     |  |    #4     |  |
              |  |<- 100px ->|  |<- 100px ->|  |
              |  |           |  |           |  |
              |  |___________|  |___________|  |
              |   ___________                  |
              |  |           |                 |
              |  |    #5     |                 |
              |  |<- 100px ->|                 |
              |  |           |                 |
              |  |___________|                 |
              |________________________________|
```

This is actually *almost* working: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANyYL/).

*Almost*, because as you can notice, when you're *stretching the width*, a blank space may appear on the right of the grid. This is because of the `float: left` CSS property, and is quite understandable.

But, is there any way to *distribute* this blank space between the *cells*, i.e. automatically increase the margins between the *cells*, until there is enough space to fit a new *cell*?

In other words, there is currently a fixed margin of 15px, and I'm looking for a kind of *min-margin* of 15px, that auto-grows while *stretching the width*, and goes back to 15px once a new *cell* fitted the first row.

To illustrate, instead of:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________
|   ___________    ___________    ___________    ___________        |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |       |
|  |    #1     |  |    #2     |  |    #3     |  |    #4     | BLANK |
|  |<- 100px ->|  |<- 100px ->|  |<- 100px ->|  |<- 100px ->| SPACE |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |       |
|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|       |
|   ___________                                                     |
|  |           |                                                    |
|  |    #5     |                                                    |
|  |<- 100px ->|                                                    |
|  |           |                                                    |
|  |___________|                                                    |
|___________________________________________________________________|
```

Having something like:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________
|    ___________     ___________     ___________     ___________    |
|   |           |   |           |   |           |   |           |   |
|   |    #1     |   |    #2     |   |    #3     |   |    #4     |   |
|   |<- 100px ->|   |<- 100px ->|   |<- 100px ->|   |<- 100px ->|   |
|   |           |   |           |   |           |   |           |   |
|   |___________|   |___________|   |___________|   |___________|   |
|    ___________                                                    |
|   |           |                                                   |
|   |    #5     |                                                   |
|   |<- 100px ->|                                                   |
|   |           |                                                   |
|   |___________|                                                   |
|___________________________________________________________________|
```

See, the margins are larger in the second illustration, so there is no blank space anymore.

Is there any solution?

Please note that the `#5` *cell* has to be left-aligned too, i.e. an `align-center` CSS property won't suit my needs (as far as I know).

Moreover, I'll be using jQuery 1.10 and Bootstrap 3, so any solution using one (or more) of these libraries is also welcomed ;)

Comment: Is this what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ANyYL/4/?

Comment: @j08691 very interesting use of `text-align: justify;`!

Comment: I think j08691's solution is as close as you'll get with pure CSS. So I think you'll need javascript (/ jQuery).

Comment: Really nice aproach with CSS the problem is you can't keep the structure for the second line.

Comment: @j08691 Well, you had a really nice idea! But when you have 3 *cells* on the first row and 2 on the second one, the layout of the second line is quite messed up, because `#5` isn't aligned with `#2`...

Comment: @sp00m have you had the time to looks at my answer? does it fullfill your requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a jQuery script that fixes your problem.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANyYL/84/).  I wrote the script where you do not have to change it at all.  You just set your minimum margin as the margin in the CSS and add as many `<li>` elements you want.

```js
function setMargin() {
  ulWidth = $('ul').innerWidth();
  boxWidth = $('li').outerWidth();
  boxMargin = parseInt($('li').css('margin'));
  maxBoxNum = $("ul li").length;
  boxNum = Math.floor((ulWidth / (boxWidth + boxMargin)));
  totalMargin = ulWidth - (boxNum * boxWidth);
  eachMargin = totalMargin / (boxNum + 1);
  if (eachMargin < boxMargin) {
    boxNum -= 1;
    totalMargin = ulWidth - (boxNum * boxWidth);
    eachMargin = totalMargin / (boxNum + 1);
  }
  if (boxNum > maxBoxNum) {
    boxNum = maxBoxNum;
    totalMargin = ulWidth - (boxNum * boxWidth);
    eachMargin = totalMargin / (boxNum + 1);
  }
  $('li').css('margin-left', eachMargin);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setMargin();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  setMargin();
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>#1</li>
  <li>#2</li>
  <li>#3</li>
  <li>#4</li>
  <li>#5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use width in percents and know that grid cells are more than 3 - the best way is to use media queries like [`this fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/5qsXP/6/show/). You will fill empty margins by cell size increase.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants fixed-width divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using only CSS. I am talking about media queries. Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/KrA6M/)** I made. It shows you can use calculation to position your squares with equal margins between each other. The margin between elements and window is also the same.

I didn't write the code for screens wider than 751px though but you get the idea. Here is the code :

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.wrap {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.foto {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gold;
  position: absolute;
}

#warning {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 631px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(4n+2),
  .wrap:nth-child(4n+3) {}
  .wrap .foto {
    top: -75px;
    margin-top: 100%;
    right: -30px;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(4n+2) {
    margin: 0 5% 0 7.5%;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(4n+3) {
    margin-right: 7.5%;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(4n+2) .foto {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(4n+3) .foto {
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -75px;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(4n) .foto {
    left: -30px;
  }
  #container {
    margin-top: -45px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 631px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 33.3%;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(3n+2) {
    margin: 0 12.5%;
  }
  .wrap .foto {
    top: -75px;
    margin-top: 100%;
    right: -37px;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(3n+2) .foto {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(3n) .foto {
    left: -37px;
  }
  #container {
    margin-top: -37px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 331px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 33.3%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    clear: left;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
  }
  .wrap .foto {
    top: -75px;
    margin-top: 100%;
    right: -50px;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(even) .foto {
    left: -50px;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(4n+3) .foto,
  .wrap:nth-child(4n+4) .foto {
    bottom: -75px;
    margin-bottom: 100%;
  }
  #container {
    margin-top: -25px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 330px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    clear: left;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(odd) .foto {
    right: -75px;
    bottom: 0;
    bottom: -75px;
    margin-bottom: 100%;
  }
  .wrap:nth-child(even) .foto {
    top: 0px;
    right: -75px;
    top: -75px;
    margin-top: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 751px) {
  #warning {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">13</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">14</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="foto">15</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- FOLLOWING JUST FOR THE DEMO -->

<div id="warning">I haven't written the code for windows bigger than 751px.<br/> You must resize this window under 751px.</div>
```